# How to process dynamic added html form on NodeJS express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My JQuery code appends html form to the DOM like this.

```
 $("#form-container").empty().append("<form method='POST' action='/process-form' id='my-form'>
    <input name='myfield'>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>")
```

And my server side code looks like this

```
   //I have app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}) middleware
   router.post('/process-form',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
   })
```

The console.log returns an empty object. However, when I create a new page with just the form and submit the form, it returns the form values as expected. Any help why it behaves like that?

EDIT:
JQuery code for AJAX request

```
$(document).on('submit', '#my-form', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        let url = $(this).attr('action')
        let method = $(this).attr('post')
        $.ajax({
            url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)

            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: could it be because you forgot the quotes around `POST` ? ( `method='POST' ...`)

Comment: Do you really have line breaks in the middle of your jQuery string?  You can't do that in Javascript with quote marks.  You can do that with backtick template strings.

Comment: My post is quoted, thanks for the observation. I added linebreak to ease reading. The form displays fine. Problem is geting the formdata at the backend (express).

Comment: Does the `POST` within your development tools networking tab look correct for the dynamic form?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with the exact code you show.  If I type "aaa" into the input element of the form added by jQuery 3.x and hit the submit button, I see `{ myfield: 'aaa' }` in the server console.  There must be something else involved in your problem that you aren't showing us.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just made an edit to the question. I added the code for AJAX request. Perhaps that helps to recreate the problem. When I use that AJAX request, it returns an empty object. But when I send the form on a separate page, it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't sending any data with our Ajax post.  You have to get the data from the form and send it yourself for an Ajax call.

There are numerous ways to get the data out of the form and package it up for jQuery.  One way which puts it in the URLencoded form is to get the DOM element for the form and execute `const formData = form.serialize()` and then send that in the `data` property for `$.ajax()`.

You could put that together like this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#my-form', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let url = $(this).attr('action')
    let method = $(this).attr('post')
    $.ajax({
        url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Oh,thanks a lot! It was a pretty silly oversight. THANK YOU, THANK YOU!